# XSL transformation from EAD to MARC skips over 2nd subject term

Tags: xml, xslt, marc

I have a very strange problem. I have XML documents encoded in EAD that I'm transforming into MARC records for a library catalog. There is a section of the EAD document that looks like this:

```
    <controlaccess>
        <list type="simple">
            <item><subject encodinganalog="650" source="lcsh">Prisons -- History -- 19th century</subject></item>
            <item><subject encodinganalog="650" source="lcsh">Prisons -- Statistics -- History -- 19th century</subject></item>
            <item><subject encodinganalog="650" source="lcsh">Prisons -- Statistics -- Extra term 1 -- History -- 19th century</subject></item>
            <item><subject encodinganalog="650" source="lcsh">Prisons -- Statistics -- Extra term 1 -- Extra term 2 -- History -- 19th century</subject></item>
        </list>
    </controlaccess>
```

What the code does correctly is pull out each item/subject and create a MARC field for each one, and each term that's separated by "--" gets put into a separate subfield (either a, x, y, or whatever).

The code does this properly if there are 1-3 terms in a single subject element, but if there are 4 or more terms, the second term gets left out entirely and the rest of the terms (from the third one on) are extracted properly. I can't figure out why the second term gets skipped over if there are 4+ terms. That's what I'd like your help figuring out.

I'm using XSL 1.0 and the subject portion of the code looks like this. The parameter gets called properly from the main template.

```
<xsl:template name="subject_template">
        <xsl:param name="string" />
        <marc:datafield>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($string, '--')!=0">
                    <xsl:variable name="tmp1" select="substring-before($string, '--')" />
                    <xsl:variable name="tmp2" select="substring-after($string, '--')" />
                    <marc:subfield code="a">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$tmp1" />
                    </marc:subfield>
                    <xsl:call-template name="subject_tokenize">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$tmp2" />
                        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'x'" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <marc:subfield code="a">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
                    </marc:subfield>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </marc:datafield>
    </xsl:template>
```

Here is the tokenize template, which is hundreds of lines long. I tried to only include what was necessary/relevant to my problem.. The 4 variables in the beginning (genx, etc) pull from a huge list of terms to determine what the subfield code should be.

```
<xsl:template name="subject_tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:param name="type" />
    <xsl:variable name="genx">
        <xsl:call-template name="genx" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="geny">
        <xsl:call-template name="geny" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="formlist">
        <xsl:call-template name="formlist" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="geoglist">
        <xsl:call-template name="geoglist" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="contains($string, '--')!=0">
        <xsl:variable name="str1" select="substring-before($string, '--')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="str2" select="substring-after($string, '--')"/>
        <xsl:if test="contains($str2, '--')!=0">
            <xsl:variable name="newstr2" select="substring-after($str2, '--')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="tmpvar" select="substring-before($str2, '--')"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="testsomething">
                    do stuff
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if test="contains($geoglist, translate($str1, '.', ''))!=0">
                        <marc:subfield code="z">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$str1"/>
                        </marc:subfield>
                        <xsl:if
                            test="contains($formlist, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))!=0">
                            <marc:subfield code="v">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str2, '--')"/>
                            </marc:subfield>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if
                            test="contains($geny, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))!=0">
                            <marc:subfield code="y">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str2, '--')"/>
                            </marc:subfield>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if
                            test="contains($genx, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))!=0">
                            <marc:subfield code="x">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str2, '--')"/>
                            </marc:subfield>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if
                            test="contains($formlist, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))=0 and contains($genx, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))=0 and contains($geny, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))=0">
                            <marc:subfield code="z">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str2, '--')"/>
                            </marc:subfield>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="contains($formlist, translate($str1, '.', ''))!=0">
                        <marc:subfield code="v">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$str1"/>
                        </marc:subfield>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="contains($geny, translate($str1, '.', ''))!=0">
                        <marc:subfield code="y">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$str1"/>
                        </marc:subfield>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if
                        test="contains($formlist, translate($str1, '.', ''))=0 and contains($geny, translate($str1, '.', ''))!=0">
                        <marc:subfield code="x">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$str1"/>
                        </marc:subfield>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="contains($geoglist, translate($str1, '.', ''))=0">
                        <xsl:if
                            test="contains($formlist, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))!=0">
                            <marc:subfield code="v">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str2, '--')"/>
                            </marc:subfield>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if
                            test="contains($geny, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))!=0">
                            <marc:subfield code="y">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str2, '--')"/>
                            </marc:subfield>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if
                            test="contains($geoglist, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))!=0">
                            <marc:subfield code="z">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str2, '--')"/>
                            </marc:subfield>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if
                            test="contains($geoglist, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))=0 and contains($geny, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))=0 and contains($formlist, translate(substring-before($str2, '--'), '.', ''))=0">
                            <marc:subfield code="x">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str2, '--')"/>
                            </marc:subfield>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:call-template name="subject_tokenize">
                        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$newstr2"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="'x'"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
```

My output looks like this:

```
=650  \0$aPrisons $x History $x 19th century
=650  \0$aPrisons $x History $x 19th century
=650  \0$aPrisons $x Extra term 1 $x History $x 19th century
=650  \0$aPrisons $x Extra term 1 $x Extra term 2 $x History $x 19th century
```

The first 650 field is correct. The following 3 are all missing the second term, "Statistics." This is just an example and has been replicated with different terms, different ordering of terms, and/or different quantity of terms. I assume the problem lies in the XSL code I showed because that's the only part of the code that should be affecting the example I provided. If nobody finds any errors in the XSL snippet, perhaps someone could take a look at the full XSL.

**UPDATE**: Here is a link (https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B647OE0WvD5-RFFPMjhqSjk3cVE&usp=sharing) to all of the files. This includes the entire XSL and XML, an additional XSL that gets imported, the resulting output MRC file, and a TXT version of the MRC file for easier viewing.

Comment: Why don't you make it easy for us and post an actual stylesheet that we could execute and reproduce the problem? Pasting together your templates and trying to reconstruct the header is unproductive.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I added the files if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: No, I meant a short version that still reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would change this:

```
<xsl:variable name="str1" select="substring-before($string, '--')"/>
<xsl:variable name="str2" select="substring-after($string, '--')"/>
```

to this:

```
<xsl:variable name="str1" select="substring-before($string, '--')"/>
<xsl:variable name="str2" select="substring-after($string, concat($str1,'--'))"/>
```

this will ensure the str2 starts after the '--' that you think it does.